# What is the purpose of the validationErrorNotifier in generated FormItems?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, web-applications, enterprise-web-library

I've got `FormItem`s getting generated against the tables in my SQL database. I'm looking through the generated `FormItem`s for my `TableModification` and I'm noticing an interesting optional parameter `Action validationErrorNotifier`.

How does one use this parameter and what benefits does it bring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a form with two phone number fields. And let's say you want to have a subsequent `Validation` that produces an error if the two phone numbers don't have matching area codes. You could use the `validationErrorNotifier` parameter in conjunction with a `bool` to make sure you only execute the subsequent `Validation` when both phone numbers are valid:

```
var phonesInvalid = false;
var stack = ControlStack.CreateWithControls(
    myTableMod.GetPhone1FormItem( ..., validationErrorNotifier: () => phonesInvalid = true, validationList: myDataMod ).ToControl(),
    myTableMod.GetPhone2FormItem( ..., validationErrorNotifier: () => phonesInvalid = true, validationList: myDataMod ).ToControl()
);
formItemBlock.Add( FormItem.Create(
    "Phone Numbers",
    stack,
    validationGetter: control => new Validation(
        ( pbv, validator ) => {
            if( !phonesInvalid && myTableMod.Phone1.AreaCode != myTableMod.Phone2.AreaCode )
                validator.NoteErrorAndAddMessage( "Area codes must match." );
        },
        myDataMod
    )
) );
```